# NullPointerException from android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper.convertSelectionToRectangles

Tags: android

I see a crash report with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper.convertSelectionToRectangles (SelectionActionModeHelper.java:343)
  at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper.startSelectionActionModeWithSmartSelectAnimation (SelectionActionModeHelper.java:308)
  at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper.lambda$l1f1_V5lw6noQxI_3u11qF753Iw (Unknown Source)
  at android.widget.-$$Lambda$SelectionActionModeHelper$l1f1_V5lw6noQxI_3u11qF753Iw.accept (Unknown Source:4)
  at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper$TextClassificationAsyncTask.onPostExecute (SelectionActionModeHelper.java:915)
  at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper$TextClassificationAsyncTask.onPostExecute (SelectionActionModeHelper.java:869)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish (AsyncTask.java:695)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600 (AsyncTask.java:180)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage (AsyncTask.java:712)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:201)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6831)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:547)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:927)
```

The stack trace does not have anything from the app's code. It is from a Redmi device. Could anyone shed some light on the possible causes of this?

This crash is from a Redmi Note 8 Pro. Based on Google Play's crash reports, Redmi devices seem to have disproportionally high crash rates.

Comment: Is SelectionActionModeHelper class part of your application? If so, please share the code from where the exception occurs.

Comment: No. I have no idea where it comes from.